# Remove padding from string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe : dat as below

```
    CODE     GROUP      SET 
1   100      6000       20.3
2   100      7000       30.1
3   DEF      8000       120
```

I'm using the statement below to format ready for insertion into XML :

```
sprintf("<rows>%s</rows>", paste(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  paste("<row>", paste(x, collapse="|"), "</row>", sep="")
}), collapse=""))


<rows><row>100|6000|     20.3</row><row>100|6000|     30.1</row><row>DEF|8000|     120</row><row>
```

The issue is that the third column is being padded with spaces.  I think this is related to the %s in sprintf.   Any ideas how I can stop this or strip the spaces?

Comment: It has to do with how `apply` calls `as.matrix` on `dat` and how the `as.matrix.data.frame` method converts your data.frame to a character matrix.

Comment: I sorted it - see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are there because `apply` calls `as.matrix` on `dat` and how the `as.matrix.data.frame` method converts your data.frame to a character matrix. An easier solution would be to use `do.call` on your data.frame instead of `apply`.

```
dat <- structure(list(CODE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("100", 
  "DEF"), class = "factor"), GROUP = c(6000L, 7000L, 8000L), SET = c(20.3, 
  30.1, 120)), .Names = c("CODE", "GROUP", "SET"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
# paste all the rows of dat together
datRows <- do.call(paste, c(dat, sep="|"))
# add </row> [something]ML tags
Row <- paste0("<row>", datRows, "</row>", collapse="")
# add </rows> tags
Rows <- sprintf("<rows>%s</rows>", Row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I stripped spaces using

```
gsub(" ","",a, fixed=TRUE)
```